# getting the parent value in Flex

Tags: apache-flex

```
private function editForm():void {
                var event:DepManagementEvent = new DepManagementEvent("Edit Page",true);
                var navi:String;
                event.navi = deleteDataGrid.selectedItem
                dispatchEvent(event);
            }
```

This function is in item renderer, i need the parent datagrid id to be called here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DataGrid(this.owner)` or `DataGrid(this.listData.owner)` would give you the parent data grid. I don't know the exact reasons, but I heard that the second one is the preferred way of doing it.

Comment: you're right, the second way is the preferred way of doing it. Also remember that the itemRenderer needs to implement IDropInListItemRenderer; many Containers don't, while many components do.

Comment: The first way will work in case of containers that don't implement the interface, right? Do you know of any specific reason why this.owner is not preferred - any problems that we might run into by using it?

Answer (score 0):

Some helpful information here:

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/itemrenderers_pt2_04.html